# What would be the best way to handle a flat data structure with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

What would be the best way to handle a flat data structure with AppleScript ?

I would like to use appleScript to get access to an Application A, extract records from that application (for example a table T of n records with 3 properties [record1, property1, property2, property3]) then use it in another Application B to retrieve the property for a given record in that Application.

For example, in B, for every record R, look if there is a matching record in T, and retrieve associate property 1 2 3 from it.
The table would be 500 to 10 000 records long.

I'm wondering :

- what data structure to store the table and access the info rapidly
- what interim storage for the table (file, clipboard, textEdit...)

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Do apps A and B exist already (and if so, what are they?), or are you creating them?
I'd suggest that serious data manipulation and AppleScript are not the best bedfellows. You're much better off using something like python, where you could easily export the data as XML, JSON, or other.

Comment: These are DAM, applications for managing catalogs of photographs

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way, which is using "Database Events" a sort of apple script front end to SQlite database. You store the data in a list of records then populate the database which is stored in your home folder. You can then access the data through (sort of) simple requests. I'm not sure it is very fast compared to other solutions, though.

Comment: You might take a look at the sqlite libs at this site… https://latenightsw.com/freeware/.